# How to copy specific data from text file to python variables iteratively

Tags: python, arrays, text-files

I have an input txt file that looks like this on my Windows device:

```
x1: [[1,2],[3,4]...]
y1: [[0,3],[5,4]...]

x2: [[1,1],[0,1]...]
y2: [[1,1],[0,1]...]

.
.
.

x500:
y500:
```

I am trying to read this into a python file and transfer the data of each pair of arrays (x# and y#) to be used in a separate function. The issue is that the arrays are not all the same size, so I cannot do a line by line approach. Is there any way where I can search for "x1: " and transfer the data until "y1: " to a variable called "x" in the python script (and then switch back between the txt and python files after each x# and y# arrays have been imported)? My goal is to automate a function given a massive list of x and y arrays.

Any advice on this?

Comment: Just use `.readlines` which will return a list of contents of each line and then You can do a line by line approach that is if those arrays are all written in one line

Comment: @Matiiss How would I be able to do this iteratively though (that is, going back and forth between the txt and python files, importing x# and y#, setting them to x and y in python, running the algorithm using x and y, then emptying x and y and restarting with x(#+1) and y(#+1)?

Comment: since `.readlines` returns a list just iterate over that list, what else do You want?